# waiting for two promises with events and loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, events, child-process

i have a piece of code like this:

```
for(let j = 0; j < someNumber; j++) {
    const forkedChildOne = fork("./child.js");
    const childOne = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        forkedChildOne.on('message', (msg){
            // someCode
            resolve(msg);
        });
    });
}

for(let i = 0; i < someAnotherNumber; i++) {
    const forkedChildTwo = fork("./child_numberTwo.js");
    const childTwo = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        forkedChildTwo.on('message', (msg){
            // someCode
            resolve(msg);
        });
    });
}
```

but here, first it wait for the first loop to complete then it goes to the second loop. but i need to run them in parallel. how can i do that? thanks.

Comment: You can't run two loops in parallel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put them in separate functions defined with the `async` keyword. Then call both functions, one after the other.

```
const forkloop = async (number, js) {
    for(let j = 0; j < number; j++) {
        const forked = fork(js);
        const child = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            forked.on('message', (msg){
                // someCode
                resolve(msg);
            });
        });
    }
}

const init = async () => {
    /* Do not await here */ forkloop(someNumber, './child.js');
    /* Do not await here */ forkloop(someAnotherNumber, './child_numberTwo.js');

}

init();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try using Promise.all ? Please try below code. I have not tested it,, but I believe it should work.

> let arrayRequests = [
> forkedChildOne.on('message'),
> forkedChildTwo.on('message') ];
>
> return Promise.all(arrayRequests).then(results => {
>
> ```
> let resultForkedChildOne = results[0];
> let resultForkedChildTwo = results[1];
> ```
>
> });